# Does Azure APIM supports 405(Method Not Allowed) Status code?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, http-status-code-405

Defining an API involves creating the resources and the allowed methods for each resource. When invoking the operation (accessing the resource) with a wrong HTTP method (for example, PUT instead of GET), the API Management service returns a 404 Resource Not Found instead of a 405 Method Not Allowed.

I've been searching for this and got this from Azure Feedback:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/32626496-return-status-code-405-instead-of-404-when-wrong-m

Still I'm not sure about it as the above answer is an year old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still a limitation, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed a confirmation.